# Does a const variable store the value in the variable?

Tags: c++

I was messing around in C++ and wrote this code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int x = 10;
    const int* ptr = &x;

    *((int*)ptr) = 11;

    std::cout << "ptr -> " << ptr << " -> " << *((int*)ptr) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x ->   " << &x << " -> " << x << std::endl;
}
```

Interestingly, the output in the console is:

```
ptr -> 00CFF77C -> 11
x ->   00CFF77C -> 10
```

I checked the value at the memory address of `ptr` and the value is `11`, so does this imply that `const` variables store the value in them, and not in memory? And if this were the case, why have a memory address storing the value?

Answer (score 6):

Your code has **Undefined Behavior**.

`x` is a **compile time constant**, so the compiler expects it to not change value at runtime. As such, the compiler is allowed to *optimize* code by substituting uses of `x`'s value with the literal value `10` *at compile time*.

So, at the point where `<< x` is used, your compiler is emitting code for `<< 10` instead.

But, since your code is also using `&x`, the compiler is *required* to make sure that `x` has a memory address accessible at runtime. That means allocating a physical `int` and initializing its value to 10. Which you are then fiddling with in an unsafe manner, despite the fact that most compilers will likely place that `int` in read-only memory.

That is why you are seeing the output you see. But you are lucky your code is not crashing outright, trying to assign a new value to a constant at runtime.

Comment: @ZeroSevenTen Please have a look at the [help page here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for information on what you can do when someone answers your question and how to thank other users. Please note that writing pure "Thank you" comments is discouraged.

Comment: "you are lucky your code is not crashing outright".

it's the other way around. the fact that the code can produce junk with no warning whatsoever is very dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of a program that writes to a `const` variable is undefined.  It could print "10", it could print "11", it could print "3822", it could crash, or it could make demons fly out of your nose.

---

That said, in this case the behavior makes perfect sense.  The compiler knows `x` is never allowed to change, so it transforms your `std::cout << x` to basically `std::cout << 10`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense.